# inserting the records in the c# form

Tags: c#

I am working with *C#*.

I want to insert record in the table. I m using the *MS Access* database. I have the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
        Data Source=C:\\Documents and Settings\\mayur patil\\
                       My Documents\\Dairy_db\\tblCompany.mdb";
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(
       "INSERT INTO tblCompany (CoCode,CoName_mar)
       VALUES("+textBox1.Text+","+textBox4.Text+")", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    this.Hide();
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.ShowDialog();
}
```

I am not getting the answer..

Comment: Are you getting any exception? What are the data types of CoCode,CoName_mar?

Comment: yuup...it is giving the error in "INSERT INTO" command...

Comment: Could you please put the whole exception message?

Comment: @Haris Hasan:- yes the names are correct

Comment: the error is pointed to the"INSERT INTO COOMMAND" and "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();"....

Comment: "INSERT INTO tblCompany (CoCode,CoName_mar)
       VALUES('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox4.Text+"')", con); Using single quote try this

Comment: @Viswanathan Iyer ;- thnx i will try it

Comment: @Rockstar try it and tell whether it works or not.

Comment: @Rockstar welcome hope.. feeling happy i could help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much better way to create your command would be to add parameters to it.

This frees you completely from thinking about the neccessity of quotes and, as an important "side effect" you eliminate the risk of SQL injection attacks. :-)

You can find a more complete explanation on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx), for example.

Your command might then look like this:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(
   "INSERT INTO tblCompany (CoCode,CoName_mar)
   VALUES(@ParamCoCode, @ParamCoName_mar)", con);

OleDbParameter paramCoCode = new OleDbParameter();
paramCoCode.ParameterName = "@ParamCoCode";
paramCoCode.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
paramCoCode.Value = categoryName;

OleDbParameter paramCoName_mar = new OleDbParameter ();
paramCoName_mar.ParameterName = "@ParamCoCode";
paramCoName_mar.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
paramCoName_mar.Value = categoryName;

// Add the parameters to the Parameters collection. 
cmdParameters.Add(paramCoCode);
cmdParameters.Add(paramCoName_mar);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Please keep in mind that the parameters need to be added in the same order as thay occur in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 4):

You need to surround the values in single quotes:

```
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(
       "INSERT INTO tblCompany (CoCode,CoName_mar)
       VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "')", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column CoName_mar is of string type you would need to change the INSERT statement as follows:

```
INSERT INTO tblCompany (CoCode,CoName_mar)
       VALUES(" + textBox1.Text + ", '" + textBox4.Text + "')"
```

Just notice the singe quote character before and after the textBox4 value.

I am presuming CoCode is of numeric type.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

can you please give providerName="System.Data.OleDb" in the connection string and check whether you can access the db with that connection string